# What is the correct capitalization of 'Vim'?

Tags: help-system, history-of

What is the proper way to capitalize 'vim'? I have seen these variants being used:

- vim
- Vim
- ViM
- VIM

Which is the correct one? Or are they all considered correct? If I look at the `:help` files, I see several styles being used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it isn't really about Vim so much as about the English language. It might be on-topic on [english.se], but I would read their help center / ask on chat first.

Comment: @Doorknob The spelling of application names is often irregular, and doesn't
follow 'normal' English gammer rules on the subject. The correct answer is usually 'whatever the
author says is correct', see for example LaTeX, GnuPG, iOS, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: The answer is too easy to find in the doc for that question to be of any use.

Comment: @romainl I didn't time it, but I think it took me 20 to 30 minutes to find
this answer ... Not the most difficult, but not very easy either. You need to
know where to look :-) ...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This actually took quite some searching, but the correct way is 'Vim'. From
[`:help pronounce`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#pronounce):

> Vim is pronounced as one word, like Jim, not vi-ai-em.  It's written with a capital, since it's a name, again like Jim.

Some parts of the Vim documentation does the all-caps 'VIM' though, this seems
to be older documentation.
I could not find any references 'ViM' in the documentation, except for a single obvious typo.

I'm not sure about the spelling of Gvim; it's spelled as 'gvim', 'Gvim', 'GVim', and 'gVim' at various places in the documentation; but 'gvim '(no capitals) is the most common by far (560, 57, 5, and 8). I suspect because gvim is just a name of a commandline tool (as a convenient alias of `vim -g`) rather than a proper name in it's own right.

Comment: http://www.vim.org spells it as `gVim` right in the front page in article.